# Styling of combobox arrow button in synth

Tags: java, swing, combobox, look-and-feel, synth

I'm creating Swing app and styling it with Synth L&F. When I enabled Synth L&F, combobox arrow button became not visible (I believe, default background is applied). If I click on a place where arrow button is intended to be, it behaves as intended - show list of choices. 
I'm trying to show it, but I can't find correct binding to be applied to this button:

```
<style id="arrowStyle">
    <state value="DEFAULT">
        <insets top="4" left="15" bottom="4" right="4"/>
        <color value="RED" type="BACKGROUND"/>
        <color value="RED" type="TEXT_BACKGROUND"/>
        <color value="GREEN" type="TEXT_FOREGROUND"/>
    </state>
    <state value="ENABLED">
        <insets top="4" left="15" bottom="4" right="4"/>
        <color value="RED" type="BACKGROUND"/>
        <color value="RED" type="TEXT_BACKGROUND"/>
        <color value="GREEN" type="TEXT_FOREGROUND"/>
    </state>
    <state value="PRESSED">
        <insets top="4" left="15" bottom="4" right="4"/>
        <color value="RED" type="BACKGROUND"/>
        <color value="RED" type="TEXT_BACKGROUND"/>
        <color value="GREEN" type="TEXT_FOREGROUND"/>
    </state>
    <state value="SELECTED">
        <insets top="4" left="15" bottom="4" right="4"/>
        <color value="RED" type="BACKGROUND"/>
        <color value="RED" type="TEXT_BACKGROUND"/>
        <color value="GREEN" type="TEXT_FOREGROUND"/>
    </state>
</style>
<bind style="arrowStyle" type="name" key="ComboBox.arrowButton"/>
```

If I apply this style, button don't appear. I don't know where is the problem - am I using correct state? color types? binding?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct binding:

```
  <bind style="arrowButton" key="ComboBox.arrowButton" type="name"/>
```

So far I haven't found how to use colors and states to style combobox arrow button, but predefined image works and is sufficient for my needs:

```
<imagePainter method="arrowButtonBackground" path="/controls/combobox_arrow_button.jpg" sourceInsets="8 8 8 8"/>
```